# Getting Out of Memory Error for Join Algorithm

Tags: python, memory

I got a dataset, sitting in a .txt file, consisting of 10 million rows in the form of RDF triples, like such:

```
wsdbm:User0 wsdbm:follows   wsdbm:User300 .
wsdbm:User6 wsdbm:likes wsdbm:Product92 .
wsdbm:Product0  rev:hasReview   wsdbm:Review478 .
wsdbm:User2 wsdbm:friendOf  wsdbm:User119 .
....
```

Since these are RDF triples, in our case we have

```
Subjects: User0, User6, Product, User2
Predicates: follows, likes, hasReview, friendOf
Objects: User300, Product92, Review478, User119
```

My goal is to write a query in the SQL form:

```
SELECT follows.subject, follows.object, friendOf.object, 
       likes.object, hasReview.object
FROM follows, friendOf, likes, hasReview
WHERE follows.object = friendOf.subject
      AND friendOf.object = likes.subject
      AND likes.object = hasReview.subject
```

So far, I create a class called PropertyTables, which has a method that iterates over the initial file and convert each subject, predicate and object into an integer to improve computational time on the join and save memory:

```
class PropertyTables():
    """
    This class holds all 4 Property Tables necessary for the required query.
    Each Property Table is an instance of the class 'PropertyTable'.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        self.property_tables = defaultdict()
        self.hash_map = HashDict()

    def parse_file(self, file_path, remove_prefix = False):
    
        data = open(file_path, 'r')
        for line in data:
            subj, prop, *obj = line.rstrip('\n.').split('\t')
            obj = obj[0].rstrip()
    
            if remove_prefix:
                subj, prop, obj = [self.remove_prefix(s) for s in (subj, prop, obj)]
            
            if prop in ['follows', 'friendOf', 'likes', 'hasReview']:
                self.hash_and_store(subj, prop, obj)
    
        data.close()
```

the class PropertyTable, mentioned in the docstring:

```
class PropertyTable():
    """
    This class represents a single Property Table, i.e. it holds every Subject and Object
    """

    def __init__(self):

        self.table = []


    def insert(self, r, s):
        
        # If r and s are already tuples, they get appended to the Property Table. 
        # Otherwise, we convert them to a tuple beforehand. This is mostly relevant when creating the 
        # Property Tables when reading the data.

        if type(r) == tuple:
            self.table.append(r + s)

        else:
            self.table.append((r, s))
```

The class `HashDict()` is a simple dictionary that hashes values, so we can retrieve them again after the join.

To not go to far with one post, I have now a single hash join algorithm:

```
def hash_join(self, property_1: PropertyTable, index_0, property_2: PropertyTable, index_1):

    ht = defaultdict(list)

    # Create Hash Table for table1

    for s in property_1.table:
        ht[s[index_0]].append(s)

    # Join Tables

    joined_table = PropertyTable()

    for r in property_2.table:
        for s in ht[r[index_1]]:
            joined_table.insert(s, r)

    return joined_table
```

I use this function to sequentially join each table, given the requirements from before.

```
WHERE follows.object = friendOf.subject
      AND friendOf.object = likes.subject
      AND likes.object = hasReview.subject

join_follows_friendOf = hash_join(pt.property_tables['follows'], 1, pt.property_tables['friendOf'], 0)
join_friendOf_likes = hash_join(join_follows_friendOf, 3, pt.property_tables['likes'], 0)
join_likes_hasReview = hash_join(join_friendOf_likes, 5, pt.property_tables['hasReview'], 0)
```

The result is correct for small tables, but 10 million rows simply result in an Out of Memory Error and I am looking for ways to avoid this. I am sorry for this very extensive post, but I guess some details are necessary in order for some advice!

Edit:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    53     68.0 MiB     68.0 MiB           1       @profile
    54                                             def hash_and_store(self, subj, prop, obj):
    55                                         
    56     68.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           hashed_subj, hashed_obj = self.hash_map.hash_values(subj, obj)
    57                                         
    58     68.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           if prop not in self.property_tables: 
    59                                                     self.property_tables[prop] = PropertyTable()
    60     68.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           self.property_tables[prop].insert(hashed_subj, hashed_obj)


Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    32     68.1 MiB     68.1 MiB           1       @profile
    33                                             def parse_file(self, file_path, remove_prefix = False):
    34                                         
    35     68.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           data = open(file_path, 'r')
    36                                         
    37                                                 
    38                                                 
    39                                                
    40                                         
    41     80.7 MiB      0.3 MiB      109311           for line in data:
    42     80.7 MiB      0.0 MiB      109310               subj, prop, *obj = line.rstrip('\n.').split('\t')
    43     80.7 MiB      0.5 MiB      109310               obj = obj[0].rstrip()
    44                                         
    45     80.7 MiB      0.0 MiB      109310               if remove_prefix:
    46     80.7 MiB      9.0 MiB      655860                   subj, prop, obj = [self.remove_prefix(s) for s in (subj, prop, obj)]
    47                                                     
    48     80.7 MiB      0.0 MiB      109310               if prop in ['follows', 'friendOf', 'likes', 'hasReview']:
    49     80.7 MiB      2.8 MiB       80084                   self.hash_and_store(subj, prop, obj)
    50                                         
    51     80.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           data.close()
    
    
   Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    38     80.7 MiB     80.7 MiB           1       @profile
    39                                             def hash_join(self, property_1: PropertyTable, index_0, property_2: PropertyTable, index_1):
    40                                         
    41     80.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           ht = defaultdict(list)
    42                                         
    43                                                 # Create Hash Table for table1
    44                                         
    45     81.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       31888           for s in property_1.table:
    46     81.2 MiB      0.5 MiB       31887               ht[s[index_0]].append(s)
    47                                         
    48                                                 # Join Tables
    49                                         
    50     81.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           joined_table = PropertyTable()
    51                                         
    52    203.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       45713           for r in property_2.table:
    53    203.8 MiB      0.0 MiB     1453580               for s in ht[r[index_1]]:
    54    203.8 MiB    122.6 MiB     1407868                   joined_table.insert(s, r)
    55                                             
    56    203.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return joined_table
```

Comment: Sounds like this is a case where you might be better off turning `hash_join` into a generator. Beause, otherwise, no matter what the data in `joined_table` is the result of a nested for-loop and will contain NxM items, which will remain a memory issue for large N and M.

Comment: That sounds interesting. However, I am quite new to solving such problems. Can you provide a source with further information on how to implement generators in that context?

Comment: Can you try running a line-by-line [memory profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) while processing, say, 10k rows? There are several things which can be improved in terms of memory use in your code, but it's useful to know which thing is the highest priority.

Comment: What is the intended effect of the line `self.table.append(r + s)` in the `PropertyTable.insert()` method?

Comment: If I have two rows in the form of tuples, for example `(a,b), (c,d)` it inserts `(a, b, c, d)` and so on. Or what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your question is this:

> The result is correct for small tables, but 10 million rows simply result in an Out of Memory Error and I am looking for ways to avoid this.

Following your top-level problem statement but with a less generic structure, we can do something like this:

```py
def runQuery(dataLines):
    from collections import defaultdict
    pred = dict(zip(['follows','friendOf','likes','hasReview'],range(4)))
    tables = [defaultdict(list) for _ in pred]

    def encode(s):
        if s[-1].isdigit():
            i = 0
            while s[-1 - i].isdigit():
                i += 1
            return int(s[-i:])
        if any(s.endswith(k) for k in pred):
            return sum(v for k, v in pred.items() if s.endswith(k))
        return None
    
    for line in dataLines:
        if not line:
            continue
        subj, prop, *obj = line.rstrip('\n.').split('\t')
        obj = obj[0].rstrip()
        subj, prop, obj = [encode(s) for s in (subj, prop, obj)]
        if prop is not None:
            tables[prop][subj].append(obj)

    tables = [{k:tuple(v) for k, v in table.items()} for table in tables]
    #[print(list(pred.keys())[i], tables[i], sep='\n') for i in range(len(pred))]

    # create reverse index for subject, object where subject [user] follows object [user]
    object_of_follows = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in tables[pred['follows']].items():
        for user in v:
            object_of_follows[user].add(k)
    # create reverse index for subject, object where subject [user] is friendOf object [user]
    object_of_friendOf = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in tables[pred['friendOf']].items():
        if k in object_of_follows:
            for user in v:
                object_of_friendOf[user].add(k)
    # create reverse index for subject, object where subject [user] likes object [product]
    object_of_likes = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in tables[pred['likes']].items():
        if k in object_of_friendOf:
            for product in v:
                object_of_likes[product].add(k)
    # create reverse index for subject, object where subject [product] hasReview object [review]
    object_of_hasReview = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in tables[pred['hasReview']].items():
        if k in object_of_likes:
            for review in v:
                object_of_hasReview[review].add(k)

    def addToResult(result, e):
        d = object_of_hasReview[e]
        c = {y for x in d for y in object_of_likes[x]}
        b = {y for x in c for y in object_of_friendOf[x]}
        a = {y for x in b for y in object_of_follows[x]}
        toAdd = [(ax, bx, cx, dx, e) for dx in d for cx in c for bx in b for ax in a]
        result += toAdd

    result = []
    for e in object_of_hasReview:
        addToResult(result, e)
    print(f'result row count {len(result):,}')
    return result
```

Explanation:

- Create a list of 4 tables (`follows, friendOf, likes, hasReview`), each a dictionary mapping subject to a tuple of objects
- Create 4 reverse indexes (`object_of_follows, object_of_friendOf, object_of_likes, object_of_hasReview`); for example:

  - `object_of_follows` is a dict that maps each user that is an object in `follows` to a set of users, each of which is a subject in `follows` that follows the object
  - `object_of_friendOf` is a dict that maps each object (user) in `friendOf` to a set of users, each of which is a subject (user) associated with the object in `friendOf` and is in `object_of_follows` (in other words, is an object for one or more subjects in `follows`)
  - etc.
- Explode each review that survived in `object_of_hasReview` into multiple result rows containing each unique result `follows.subject, follows.object, friendsOf.object, likes.object, hasReview.object` as specified in the query
- Return the list of all such exploded rows.

---

Test code for 10 million lines:

```py
dataLines = []
numFollowers = 1000
numChildren = 10
overlapFactor = max(1, numChildren // 2)
def largerPowerOfTen(x):
    y = 1
    while x >= y:
        y *= 10
    return y

aCeil = largerPowerOfTen(numFollowers)
bCeil = largerPowerOfTen(aCeil * numChildren)
cCeil = largerPowerOfTen(bCeil * numChildren)
dCeil = largerPowerOfTen(cCeil * numChildren)
friendOf, likes = set(), set()
for a in range(numFollowers):
    for b in range(aCeil + a * overlapFactor, aCeil + a * overlapFactor + numChildren):
        dataLines.append(f'wsdbm:User{a}    wsdbm:follows   wsdbm:User{b} .\n')
        for c in range(bCeil + b * overlapFactor, bCeil + b * overlapFactor + numChildren):
            if (b,c) not in friendOf:
                dataLines.append(f'wsdbm:User{b}    wsdbm:friendOf  wsdbm:User{c} .\n')
                friendOf.add((b,c))
            for d in range(cCeil + c * overlapFactor, cCeil + c * overlapFactor + numChildren):
                if (c,d) not in likes:
                    dataLines.append(f'wsdbm:User{c}    wsdbm:likes wsdbm:Product{d} .\n')
                    likes.add((c,d))
                for e in range(dCeil * (d + 1), dCeil * (d + 1) + numChildren):
                    dataLines.append(f'wsdbm:Product{d} wsdbm:hasReview wsdbm:Review{e} .\n')

print(f'dataLines row count {len(dataLines):,}')

from timeit import timeit
n = 1
print(f'Timeit results:')
t = timeit(f"runQuery(dataLines)", setup=f"from __main__ import dataLines, runQuery", number=n) / n
print(f'======== runQuery ran in {t} seconds using {n} iterations')
'''
result = runQuery(dataLines)
print(f'result row count {len(result):,}')
print(f'{"follows.subject":>20}{"follows.object":>20}{"friendsOf.object":>20}{"likes.object":>20}{"hasReview.object":>20}')
[print(f'{a:20}{b:20}{c:20}{d:20}{e:20}') for a,b,c,d,e in result]
'''
```

Output:

```
dataLines row count 10,310,350
Timeit results:
result row count 12,398,500
======== runQuery ran in 81.53253880003467 seconds using 1 iterations
```

---

Here's input/output from a smaller-scale sample run:

Params

```py
numFollowers = 3
numChildren = 3
overlapFactor = 2
```

Input (after storing in tables):

```
follows
{0: (10, 11, 12), 1: (12, 13, 14), 2: (14, 15, 16)}
friendOf
{10: (120, 121, 122), 11: (122, 123, 124), 12: (124, 125, 126), 13: (126, 127, 128), 14: (128, 129, 130), 15: (130, 131, 132), 16: (132, 133, 134)}
likes
{120: (1240, 1241, 1242), 121: (1242, 1243, 1244), 122: (1244, 1245, 1246), 123: (1246, 1247, 1248), 124: (1248, 1249, 1250), 125: (1250, 1251, 1252), 126: (1252, 1253, 1254), 127: (1254, 1255, 1256), 128: (1256, 1257, 1258), 129: (1258, 1259, 1260), 130: (1260, 1261, 1262), 131: (1262, 1263, 1264), 132: (1264, 1265, 1266), 133: (1266, 1267, 1268), 134: (1268, 1269, 1270)}
hasReview
{1240: (12410000, 12410001, 12410002), 1241: (12420000, 12420001, 12420002), 1242: (12430000, 12430001, 12430002, 12430000, 12430001, 12430002), 1243: (12440000, 12440001, 12440002), 1244: (12450000, 12450001, 12450002, 12450000, 12450001, 12450002, 12450000, 12450001, 12450002), 1245: (12460000, 12460001, 12460002, 12460000, 12460001, 12460002), 1246: (12470000, 12470001, 12470002, 12470000, 12470001, 12470002, 12470000, 12470001, 12470002), 1247: (12480000, 12480001, 12480002), 1248: (12490000, 12490001, 12490002, 12490000, 12490001, 12490002, 12490000, 12490001, 12490002, 12490000, 12490001, 12490002), 1249: (12500000, 12500001, 12500002, 12500000, 12500001, 12500002, 12500000, 12500001, 12500002), 1250: (12510000, 12510001, 12510002, 12510000, 12510001, 12510002, 12510000, 12510001, 12510002, 12510000, 12510001, 12510002, 12510000, 12510001, 12510002), 1251: (12520000, 12520001, 12520002, 12520000, 12520001, 12520002), 1252: (12530000, 12530001, 12530002, 12530000, 12530001, 12530002, 12530000, 12530001, 12530002, 12530000, 12530001, 12530002, 12530000, 12530001, 12530002), 1253: (12540000, 12540001, 12540002, 12540000, 12540001, 12540002, 12540000, 12540001, 12540002), 1254: (12550000, 12550001, 12550002, 12550000, 12550001, 12550002, 12550000, 12550001, 12550002, 12550000, 12550001, 12550002), 1255: (12560000, 12560001, 12560002), 1256: (12570000, 12570001, 12570002, 12570000, 12570001, 12570002, 12570000, 12570001, 12570002, 12570000, 12570001, 12570002), 1257: (12580000, 12580001, 12580002, 12580000, 12580001, 12580002, 12580000, 12580001, 12580002), 1258: (12590000, 12590001, 12590002, 12590000, 12590001, 12590002, 12590000, 12590001, 12590002, 12590000, 12590001, 12590002, 12590000, 12590001, 12590002), 1259: (12600000, 12600001, 12600002, 12600000, 12600001, 12600002), 1260: (12610000, 12610001, 12610002, 12610000, 12610001, 12610002, 12610000, 12610001, 12610002, 12610000, 12610001, 12610002, 12610000, 12610001, 12610002), 1261: (12620000, 12620001, 12620002, 12620000, 12620001, 12620002, 12620000, 12620001, 12620002), 1262: (12630000, 12630001, 12630002, 12630000, 12630001, 12630002, 12630000, 12630001, 12630002, 12630000, 12630001, 12630002), 1263: (12640000, 12640001, 12640002), 1264: (12650000, 12650001, 12650002, 12650000, 12650001, 12650002, 12650000, 12650001, 12650002), 1265: (12660000, 12660001, 12660002, 12660000, 12660001, 12660002), 1266: (12670000, 12670001, 12670002, 12670000, 12670001, 12670002, 12670000, 12670001, 12670002), 1267: (12680000, 12680001, 12680002), 1268: (12690000, 12690001, 12690002, 12690000, 12690001, 12690002), 1269: (12700000, 12700001, 12700002), 1270: (12710000, 12710001, 12710002)}
```

Output

```
result row count 351
     follows.subject      follows.object    friendsOf.object        likes.object    hasReview.object
                   0                  10                 120                1240            12410000
                   0                  10                 120                1240            12410001
                   0                  10                 120                1240            12410002
                   0                  10                 120                1241            12420000
                   0                  10                 120                1241            12420001
                   0                  10                 120                1241            12420002
                   0                  10                 120                1242            12430000
                   0                  10                 121                1242            12430000
                   0                  10                 120                1242            12430001
                   0                  10                 121                1242            12430001
                   0                  10                 120                1242            12430002
                   0                  10                 121                1242            12430002
                   0                  10                 121                1243            12440000
                   0                  10                 121                1243            12440001
                   0                  10                 121                1243            12440002
                   0                  10                 121                1244            12450000
                   0                  11                 121                1244            12450000
                   0                  10                 122                1244            12450000
                   0                  11                 122                1244            12450000
                   0                  10                 121                1244            12450001
                   0                  11                 121                1244            12450001
                   0                  10                 122                1244            12450001
                   0                  11                 122                1244            12450001
                   0                  10                 121                1244            12450002
                   0                  11                 121                1244            12450002

etc.
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote `encode()` quickly and cut some corners (sacrificed readability for brevity); it should really be rewritten as: `for k, v in pred.items(): if s.endswith(k): return v`. Because the condition will be True for exactly one key in `pred`, I used `sum()` to let me use a comprehension generator instead of a conventional for-loop around an `if`. Note that `encode()` is just intended as a reverse engineered version of your `PropertyTables.remove_prefix()` method.

Comment: What if some object, say `User101` and another Object `Product101` appear in the table? There would be no way after the query to recover if it was a user or a product, right? But in general, instead of creating single tuples for each entry, you map every object to a list of objects for the appropriate subject?

Comment: I have assumed subject and object for a given table are of just one type. So `follows` is user-pred-user, `friendOf` is user-pred-user, `likes` is user-pred-product, and `hasReview` is product-pred-review. After the query, each row in `result` contains an encoded version of  `follows.subject, follows.object, friendsOf.object, likes.object, hasReview.object` which is `user, user, user, product, review`. To decode, prepend `wsdbm:User` for user fields and `wsdbm:Product` for product fields. I hope this addresses your query, if not please let me know.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure if that is the case. However, the data is available here: https://dsg.uwaterloo.ca/watdiv/ . But I could not find information if each predicate has a unique subject and object type

Comment: A quick solution would be to modify `encode()` to replace int (currently an id that is opaque as to field type) with tuple(int, int) with the first int as an encoded field type (say 0=user, 1=product, 2=review) and the second int as the id calculated with the existing logic.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but are you not actually appending the subjects to the result each time? Because in the query we are mostly interested in objects.

Comment: I am following your SQL `SELECT` statement, so the only subject that is included in each row is `follows.subject`, the first field following `SELECT`. All other fields (`follows.object, friendOf.object, likes.object, hasReview.object`) are objects.

Comment: let's take for example : `c = {y for x in d for y in object_of_likes[x]}` . As far as I understand, this includes all subjects, of `objects_of_likes` , where there is a match between review subject `x` and the object of `likes`, just like in the query. Later you explode by going over that list `c`, but this list contains only subjects. I am pretty sure I am just stupid but I do not see my error in thinking

Comment: `objects_of_likes` is a dict with object (product) as key and a `set` of all subjects (users) in `likes` that like it (filtered to include only subjects that are objects in `object_of_friendOf`) as value. So the values in `objects_of_likes`, which are collected as a set in `c`, are indeed subjects in `likes`, but (importantly) they are also objects in `friendOf`. Recall that your SQL `SELECT` query specifies a number of fields including `friendOf.object`; this is what `c` is collecting.

Comment: I see, I think my confusion came from neglecting that some `objects` are equal do `subjects`. so the elements in `friendOf` are indeed `subjects`, but not `subjects` from `friendOf`.

Comment: Unfortunately, after hours of trying to fix it, I still get an OOM. The object tables are still quite big, resulting in a huge result table. So it dies quite fast aswell

Comment: Your SQL query effectively does this: given every review of every product that was liked by any user who was a friend of any other user who is followed by any user, for each such review create a result row containing every combination of follower (user), friendOf subject (user) and friendOf object (user who liked the reviewed product). I can see how that could potentially result in a huge number of rows. Is what I described here what you actually need, or could you live with a different (more compact) result?

Comment: It is actually exactly what I need, that is why I am sad that I cannot make it work. What do you mean with more compact result though?

Comment: For example, suppose you had a result with one row for each product/liker/friend/follower. If there are an average of 100 reviews per product, this result would be 100 times smaller than the one that replicates each such row for every product review. As a separate question: in which part of the code in my answer do you get an OOM?

Comment: Maybe we should move to chat btw. I get the OOM after the first join basically. So using `d` and `c` is fine, using `d`, `c` and `b` is not.

Comment: btw, I thought a little bit more about the problem and I wondered if we really need to include `d` in the last list comprehension? By doing so, we take all subjects of `hasReview`, without any specified relation. To be more precise, `c` already includes `hasReview.subject`, and thus should also hold the other pair `hasReview.object`. With nested loops we add more than needed,  I think?

Comment: Removing `d` would remove one field of the 5 total per result row, but I believe you would still have on the order of trillions of rows for the data sample I saw, which is the primary difficulty.

Comment: Also, by construction in the code in my answer, we don't take all subjects of `hasReview`, just the ones that match the query filter (i.e., they are objects in likes where subject is an object in friendOf where subject is an object in follows).

Comment: I agree, but in `d = object_of_hasReview[e]` are subjects, which do not have a join attribute in `likes` right? `toAdd = [(ax, bx, cx, dx, e) for dx in d`, and yet,  we are including every subject, I think I just have an error in my thinking though

Comment: `object_of_hasReview` does not include reviews for all products, only for those that are in `object_of_likes`. Similarly `object_of_likes` only includes products in `object_of_friendOf`. And `object_of_friendOf` only includes `friendOf` objects (users) for subjects (users) in `object_of_follows`. Finally, `object_of_follows` only includes users that have followers. So I believe the "join attribute" you reference is implicit in `object_of_hasReivew`.